# Pushing scope form to array changing other members of the array

Tags: angularjs

This is quite a weird problem, I have a form create a new object and then push it to an array. However, new items are changing the ones before it.

```
var newHeli = $scope.hlz.form;
    $scope.helicopters.push(newHeli);
    $scope.selectedHelicopters.push(newHeli)
```

Will add a new helicopter, but it changes the values of previous helicopters. Where the name is even being updated before it is submitted.

```
 <button class="helicopter" ng-click="removeHelicopter($index)" 
 ng-repeat="helicopters in selectedHelicopters  track by $index">
   {{helicopters.size}}
 </button>
```

Is how it is displayed and

```
<input type="text"  ng-model="hlz.form.size"/>
```

is how the model is updated for new entries. So where the array should have entries like:

`[{size: 'test 1'}, {size: 'test 2'}, {size: 'test 3'}]`

it has:

```
 [{size: 'test 3'}, {size: 'test 3'}, {size: 'test 3'}]
```

Any clue how to resolve this?

Comment: Once you push the heli into the array, you need to create a new, blank object to take the next one.

Comment: I assumed I was doing that by reinitializing the var.

Comment: I'm looking for a line of code like $scope.hlz.form = {}; and not seeing it. Alternatively, you could use Avi's suggestion and use angular.extend() to create a copy of the object.

Comment: I will probably do that instead. The form is auto filled from a previous object, I would rather not make it static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pushing a reference to object, this is not a deep clone

Comment: This is correct. For the record I changed my code to         var newHeli =angular.copy($scope.hlz.form); and it fixed it